# Printing list item above tqdm progress bar fails to replace the previous item instead adds a new line

Tags: python, loops, urllib, sys, tqdm

I am attempting to read urls from a text file "url.com", append them to a list, then iterate the list to check if the url is an active website.

I am having problems with tqdm, I don't know to make the current list item replace the previous list item when iterating my group of urls.

Can someone guide me on how to properly replace the previous iterated item without a newline (with tqdm)?

```
import urllib
from tqdm.auto import tqdm, trange
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

with open(r"millard.txt", 'r') as fp:
    total_lines = len(fp.readlines())
    print('Total Number of lines:', total_lines)

score_list = []
working = []
not_working = []
cntr = 0
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('millard.txt', 'r'))
danky = "Progress"

with open('millard.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in tqdm(f, total=num_lines, position=0, leave=False, desc=danky):
        # print(line)

        # url = i.strip()  # to remove the trailing \n
        new_link = "http://www.{poop}".format(poop=i)
        print("Getting %s" % new_link, end="")
        # try block to read URL
        try:
            post = urllib.request.urlopen(new_link)
            # print(post.__dict__)
            working.append(new_link)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            # print(e.__dict__)
            fss = 1
        except urllib.error.URLError as e:
            # print(e.__dict__)
            fss = 1
        cntr += 1
        time.sleep(0.01)

with open(r'final.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for item in working:
        # write each item on a new line
        fp.write("%s" % item)
    print('Done')
```

Tried a lot, just need the script to not print out a list of urls, instead print each url in the same line as the group/list etc. is being iterated.

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from socket import error as SocketError
import errno

with open(r"millard.txt", 'r') as fp:
    total_lines = len(fp.readlines())
    print('Total urls loaded:', total_lines)

working = []
not_working = []

num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('millard.txt', 'r'))

urls = []
f = open('millard.txt', 'r+')
f1 = f.readlines()

for i in f1:
    urls.append(i.rstrip())

for i in (pbar := tqdm(urls, total=num_lines, position=0, leave=True, desc=".")):
    # print(line)

    # url = i.strip()  # to remove the trailing \n
    new_link = "http://www.{poop}".format(poop=i)

    # try block to read URL
    import urllib.request

    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}

    try:
        req = urllib.request.Request(new_link, headers=hdr)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        response.read()
        code = " - success"
        working.append(new_link)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        # status = e.__dict__
        code = " - failed"
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        # status = e.__dict__
        code = " - failed"
    except SocketError as e:
        # if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
        code = " - failed"

    pbar.set_description(f"Checking: {i}{code}")

with open(r'final.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for item in working:
        # write each item on a new line
        fp.write("%s \n" % item)

with open(r"final.txt", 'r') as fp:
    total_lines = len(fp.readlines())
    print('Total urls loaded:', total_lines)
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.